# How to properly parse JSON string data containing location information to create Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am getting latitude and longitude as strings from a JSON response. I am parsing the response, extracting them and then storing them in an array. I am then using the array to populate markers on map using Google Maps.

My issue is, when I hard code the values in the locations array e.g:
`var locations = [["Happy Restaurant", 37.328255, -121.883693]];` 
The marker is populated successfully. But when I use `locations.push([f.restaurant_name, parseFloat(Number(f.address.latitude)), parseFloat(Number(f.address.longitude))]);` The markers are not populated on map.
Hard coded values work perfectly but somehow, it is not able to populate the map using my array populated from JSON parsed response which has the same data. I tried using `parseFloat` and `Number` methods. Also tried `toString`. Nothing seems to work. What am I missing here?

my code:

map.js:

```
var locations = [];
$.getJSON("http://localhost:63342/295%20Project/api/response.json?",
  function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, f) {
      //Log prints accurate data
      console.log(f.restaurant_name + " " + parseFloat(Number(f.address.latitude)) + " " + parseFloat(Number(f.address.longitude)));

      // tried using Number() parseFloat() and parseFloat(Number()) without success
      locations.push(f.restaurant_name, parseFloat(Number(f.address.latitude)), parseFloat(Number(f.address.longitude)));
    });
  });
//create the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.328255, -121.883693),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker;
var i;
//populate the markers on map (works with hardocded values in the locations array)
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      //redirect markers to restaurant_detail.html
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

response.json:

```
[{
  "restaurant_name": "Happy Eating",
  "address": {
    "longitude": -121.883693,
    "city": "San Jose",
    "zip": "95112",
    "latitude": 37.328255,
    "state": "CA",
    "street_address": "545 S Second St"}
  }]
```

html:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Try `log`ging the stringified `location` and see how it differs from when you define it outright. (also, why `parseFloat(Number(`?)

Comment: It does not differ at all. The log displays exactly what I want. Thats the funny part.

Comment: I tried `parseFloat` , `Number` and `parseFloat(Number(?))` , all 3 dont work

Comment: Your backend seems to be broken - the JSON is not properly formatted, so parsing it will throw an error.

Comment: Sorry, the response I added above was missing a "}" parenthesis, added that in the question. The JSON shows as valid, I checked using jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing `locations[i][1]` as if `locations[i]` is an array, but you're `push`ing individual primitives to `locations` currently. Try pushing *arrays* to `locations` instead:

```
locations.push([f.restaurant_name, f.address.latitude, f.address.longitude]);
```

Also, rather than messing with IIFEs to deal with `var`'s function scope problems, you would probably find it far easier to write code using `let`, which has block scope and is a lot easier to deal with. Or, even better, use `forEach` to iterate directly.

The other problem is that you need to make sure the map gets populated *after* the call to localhost, not before. As is, your code that creates the map runs immediately after the request is made, without waiting for the response. Instead, create the map only after the response comes back:

```
fetch('http://localhost:63342/295%20Project/api/response.json?')
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((data) => {
  const locations = data.map(({ restaurant_name, address: { latitude, longitude }}) => (
    [restaurant_name, latitude, longitude]
  ));
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.328255, -121.883693),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  locations.forEach(([name, lat, lng]) => {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
      infowindow.setContent(name);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried both your suggestions, still does not populate the markers.

Comment: See edit - you weren't waiting for the response to come back before creating the map, so `locations` was empty at the time the map was created.

Comment: Not waiting for the response to come back before creating the map was the problem. Thanks a ton! :)